# Как вернуть папку которую я случайно удалил

Tags: git, bash, github

локально удалил папку из проекта успел ее только закоммитить
, **`git`** знает что она удалена .

- но я вносил изменения в другие файлы,
- в репозитории та папка есть ,

  как ее слить обратно при этом не затереть свои изменения в других файлах ?

Comment: `git checkout -- имя_папки`

Comment: если свои изменения в этой папке не добавил (`git add`), то они гарантированно потеряются...

Comment: @KoVadim а если я не помню имя папки ?

Comment: Вы же пишете, что git знает, что она удалена. Значит `git status` и смотреть

Comment: `git` уже  не показывает эту папку после комита он показывает новые изменения

Comment: тогда самый простой вариант для Вас. Склонируйте репозиторий в другую папку, откатитесь там до нужного коммита, заберите папку.

Comment: *если я не помню имя* — см. `$ git log --name-status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мне помогло это

> **git** checkout  HEAD^ *fileName*

просто слил папку обратно в не зависимости от комита